# C# Problems importing a file to an array and put each character in it's own index

Tags: arrays, file, import, character

I have a problem importing a text file to an array and put each character in it's own index?
Here is my code:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string content = File.ReadAllText("Labyrint.txt", Encoding.UTF8);

        // Use ToCharArray to convert string to array.
        char[] array = content.ToCharArray();

        Console.WriteLine(content);
        // Loop through array.
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            // Get character from array.
            char letter = array[i];
            // Display each letter.
            Console.Write("Letter: " + letter);
           // Console.WriteLine(letter);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is it only display some of the characters? Now if I change the code a little to this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string content = File.ReadAllText("Labyrint.txt", Encoding.UTF8);

        // Use ToCharArray to convert string to array.
        char[] array = content.ToCharArray();

        Console.WriteLine(content);
        // Loop through array.
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            // Get character from array.
            char letter = array[i];
            // Display each letter.
            Console.Write("Letter: " + letter);
            //Console.WriteLine(letter);
        }
    }
}
```

Then it display all the charaters in the array, but when I try to find out what index each character are in and add the 'i' to this code  Console.Write("Letter: " + letter); so the code looks like this:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string content = File.ReadAllText("Labyrint.txt", Encoding.UTF8);

        // Use ToCharArray to convert string to array.
        char[] array = content.ToCharArray();

        Console.WriteLine(content);
        // Loop through array.
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            // Get character from array.
            char letter = array[i];
            // Display each letter.
            Console.Write(" Letter: " + letter + "  " + i);
            //Console.WriteLine(letter);
        }
    }
}
```

The result go crazy and look like this:
[Output Vindue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CGUS.png)
The text file is the one below, and I placed it in the debug folder in my project so I didn't had to provide a path.

[TextFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVMIJ.png)

Comment: have you tried `Console.Write(" Letter: {0} {1}", letter, i)`to take advantage of the built-in String.Format functionality of Console.Write and Console.WriteLine?

Comment: Also, consider that the characters of data you are reading may not be printable. Think spaces, tabs, carriage returns, line feeds, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code and it seems to work, if this still doesn't work it's likely you're using the wrong encoding type and the file has a different encoding than UTF-8.

If that is the case then open the file in an editor like Notepad++ and see what the encoding for the file is

**EDIT**
The reason it looks like it was starting at line 191 instead of 0 was you were exceeding the buffer height of the console, so below I've added code to set the buffer height to it's maximum. depending on the application you might want to use a smaller value.

```
class Program{
    static void Main(string[] args){
        //Increase Console Buffer Height
        Console.BufferHeight = Int16.MaxValue - 1;
        string content = File.ReadAllText(@"Labyrint.txt", Encoding.UTF8);

        // Use ToCharArray to convert string to array.
        char[] array = content.ToCharArray();

        // Loop through array
        for (int i =0; i<array.Length; i++) {
            string letter = arrray[i].ToString()
                .Replace("\r","\\r").Replace("\n", "\\n")
                .Replace("\t","\\t").Replace(" ","<space>");
            // Display each letter
            Console.WriteLine("Letter {0}: {1}", i, letter); 
        } 
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taken the time to try to solve the problem but in my output window it starts with 191 ? when it should start with 0. Unfortunately I can't attach an image when I make a comment here but this is how the first lines look like: Letter 191: +  (next line) Letter 192: <space> (next line) Letter 193:  +         etc.

Comment: if the begining of your `for` loop looks like this `for(int i=0;` then it will start at character 0. is it possible because it will output so many lines the console window scrolls down, have you tried scrolling up?

Comment: I know, and that is what bothers me like crazy. It should start at 0, but the output window shows 489 at the bottom and when I scroll the output window up to the top it shows 191.

Comment: ok the issue was you were exceeding the `Console.BufferHeight` with the number of lines output see my updated answer.

Comment: Yes that did the trick. Thanks for your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: If this answered your question please select it as answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sorry I am new here, but I clicked the arrow next to your answer. Unfortunately I have less than 15 in reputation so it was not shown but only recorded.

Comment: By the way, if you have any idea of how I remove the first line from the imported text file and afterwards place it in a char array that would be great. My question about that is to be find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43189953/problems-reading-a-textfile-where-i-skip-1-line-and-place-it-into-a-char-array