# Problems reading a textfile where I skip 1 line and place it into a char array

Tags: c#, arrays, text, char, skip

I have a problem reading a textfile where I skip the first line and afterwards place it into a char array.

The operation is very easy if I want to place it into an array which would looks like the code below, but again it should be a char array.

```
var content = File.ReadAllLines("Labyrint.txt");
File.WriteAllLines("Labyrint.txt", content.Skip(1).ToArray());
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Also, there is no char array in the code your provided

Comment: Do you just want to write all lines but the skipped one(s) in a single line?

Comment: A `char[]` in C# has relatively few uses. Do you mean you want all of the lines in one `string`? How would you use this?

Comment: The text file is a Labyrinth that I place in an char array because I want to know exactly which indices in the array that are walls (the indices that contain a character) and which is the path the user can walk on (the empty indices).

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will have to manually read ll the lines using a stream reader like this

**EDIT**
Corrected Peek Systax

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Labyrint.txt")){
    sr.ReadLine(); //skip first Line
    while(sr.Peek()!=-1){
        sb.AppendLine(sr.ReadLine());
    }
}
char[] content = sb.ToString().ToCharArray();

File.WriteAllText("Labyrint.txt",sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I get a red line under the "peek" word saying "StreamReader does not contain a definition of peek and no extension method accepting a first argument of type StreamReader could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference). I can't see what using directive I am missing. I both have system and system IO? By the way could you please explain each line of code so it is exactly clear what it does.

Comment: Thanks MrZander that helped making the code work. However it has the exact same problem as the solution I came up with. The first time the codes run it works fine and it deletes the first line, but next time I start the program it will delete the next first line. Meaning that each time the program runs it deletes a line and save the file afterwards? I want it to import the file and delete the first line but not save the file with a line deleted. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I actually did find a way to make it work, but the problem is it only works the first time. The reason why is that the first time the program starts it deletes the first line in the file. However the file is saved with the first line deleted. So next time the program starts it will delete the new first line and so on until there are no more lines in the text file.

```
//Delete the first line in the textfile
var Labo = File.ReadAllLines("Labyrint.txt");
File.WriteAllLines("Labyrint.txt", Labo.Skip(1).ToArray());
//import the textfile after the first line has been deleted
        string content = File.ReadAllText("Labyrint.txt", Encoding.UTF8);

        // Use ToCharArray to convert string to array.
        char[] array = content.ToCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay after 1 day with frustration and different approaches I finally found the solution. Beside finding the solution I also managed to keep the code extremely simple, so it has been a great day. You guys find the correct solution below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.IO;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication25

{
class Program
{

    static char[] values;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Increase Console Buffer Height
        Console.BufferHeight = Int16.MaxValue - 1;

        foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines("Labyrint.txt", Encoding.UTF8).Skip(1))
        {
            values = line.ToCharArray();

            Console.WriteLine(values);

        }

        //finds the character on index 0
        Console.WriteLine(values[0]);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I was too fast to flatter myself, cause if you instead of 0 try to get the index of 56 then it throws an exception. And if you say Console.WriteLine(values) outside the foreach loop, it only show the last line in the output window. Anybody who knows how to save the final result from the foreach loop in a string variable, and not as it does now only save the last line? –

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if I am the only one that follow this thread or if people just don't have any clue of what to do?
Anyway I came up with a solution that now almost work. Meaning that the first line in the text file is skipped and afterwards it is with the help of stringbuilder placed in a char array. However not everything is perfect, cause when I look the elements up by the index number, they are 2 places off where they should be. Forinstens the character B should be at index 21 but for some reason it is at index 23? I checked the text file and there are no spaces after any of the lines in the textfile, and builder doesn't have a trim method, so anybody has any suggestions? You guys find my code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApplication25
{



 class Program
{

    static char[] FloridaArray;
    static string DenverString;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Increase Console Buffer Height
        Console.BufferHeight = Int16.MaxValue - 1;

        DenverString = ConvertStringArrayToString();
        FloridaArray = DenverString.ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(DenverString);
        Console.WriteLine(FloridaArray[43]);
    }

    static string ConvertStringArrayToString()
    {
        // Concatenate all the elements into a StringBuilder.
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var value in File.ReadAllLines("Labyrint.txt", Encoding.UTF8).Skip(1))
        {

            builder.Append(value);
            builder.AppendLine();
        }

        return builder.ToString();

    }
}
 }
```